# What's that suspicious file object and how to handle it?

Tags: android, file, android-4.4-kitkat, sd-card

In my Android app (Android 4.4.2) I create an object in the file system by mistake and sporadically. I don't know why it's created sometimes, but I want to identify it afterwards. Originally I want to create a directory by mkdirs() which works most of the time.

I can see this file i.e. with ES Explorer (icon is a question mark) or ls-command. ES Explorer can delete it, but i can't handle it at all:

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + getappContextStatic().getString(R.string.General_Appinfo_Name) + "/" + "res/demo" ;
    File file = new File(path);

    Log.d("MyApp", "getAbsolutePath:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d("MyApp", "exists:" + file.exists());
    Log.d("MyApp", "isDirectory:" + file.isDirectory());
    Log.d("MyApp", "isFile:" + file.isFile());
    Log.d("MyApp", "isHidden:" + file.isHidden());
    Log.d("MyApp", "canWrite:" + file.canWrite());
    Log.d("MyApp", "canRead:" + file.canRead());
    Log.d("MyApp", "getTotalSpace:" + file.getTotalSpace());
    Log.d("MyApp", "mkdirs:" + file.mkdirs());
    Log.d("MyApp", "delete:" + file.delete());
```

gives me following results:

```
    getAbsolutePath:/storage/emulated/0/myapp/res/demo
    exists:false
    isDirectory:false
    isFile:false
    isHidden:false
    canWrite:false
    canRead:false
    getTotalSpace:0
    mkdirs:false
    delete:false
```

I don't know if I is it a file, a directory, a link...? And how to handle it? Possibly I can't even build the file object?